# Aligning two divs with dynamic width and nested table with 100% width

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I'm trying to get two div's (with dynamic widths) to line up side-by-side within a parent that has 100% width; not difficult until I ran across having a nested table (also with 100% with) inside one of the divs.

**What I want:**
`#parent` width 100%
`#right` auto width caused by content within
`#left` fill the void of empty space left over from "#right"
`table` 100% width of "#left"

**Problem:**
As you can see in the example below, I can get the div's the be side-by-side, but I can not get the table to be 100% of "#left"; instead, it goes below "#parent".

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/MHWQT/

**Code:**

*html*

```html
<div id="parent">

    <div id="right">RIGHT!</div>

    <div id="left">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Also Header</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

*css*

```css
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit**
replay to an answer
I forgot to mention I'm going to be using @media properties to change everything inside `#parent` when the screen in under a certain width. So I'd like to keep the current html structure

Answer (score 2):

[The OP wrote in an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que):

> I hate posting a question and solving it shortly after, even after hours of trying to solve the problem before posting the question, **but**, I solved it none the less. I think...
>
> css
>
> ```css
> #parent {
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 300px;
>     background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
> }
>
> #right {
>     float: right;
>     width: auto;
>     height: 100%;
>     background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
> }
>
> #left {
>     position: relative;
>     overflow: hidden;
>     /*width: 100%;*/
>     height: 100%;
>     background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
> }
>
> table {
>     width: 100%;
>     background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It had been a while I worked with CSS. However, First you should be having your `left` div on top of the `right` code block. HTML and CSS goes in sequential (as far as i know)

Another thing, What you are trying to achieve for the left block would require some JavaScript to work. You should get the content of the table first and when the loads, you need to resize your `left` block according to the size of the content.

A good thing to do is to look at the lifecycle of your page load and see which part gets rendered first, based on that you can size them accordingly.

**WORKING EDITED:**

I played with your code and figured this code block will provide a "shrink-to-fit" capability.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="right">sdfdsfdsfdsfsdf</div>
    <div id="left">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Also Header</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

​CSS:

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#right {
    float:right;
    width:auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}

#left {
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
    width:100%;
}

table {
    width:300px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: See edited code for working sample. Ignore what I said earlier.

Comment: `#right` is suppose to be only as big as the content within it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I mis-read the left and right part. I changed the code now. I just interchanged the behaviour I had for left and right from my earlier code. Try it and let me know.

Comment: NOTE: You may have a small bug here. For example, If you `#parent` width is 500px and the `#right` took up more than the difference when taking the `#left` into consideration, left will be mis-aligned. (How to fix that, well I haven't looked into it)

Comment: I want the table inside `#left` to be 100% of `#left`, or rather, take up the horizontal space that `#right` is not taking up. :s

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="parent">
   <tr>
     <td id="left">
        <table id="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Also Header</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    <td id="right">RIGHT!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And change your table css to:

```
#table {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
```

​

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm going to be using @media properties to change everything inside `#parent` when the screen in under a certain width. So I'd like to keep the current html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the table width in the css, include jQuery and then include this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var new_width = $("#parent").width() - $("#right").width();

   $("table").first().css("width", new_width);

});​
```